# Cursor doesn't refresh until I restart device in android

Tags: java, android, video

I'm developing camera app now and can record videos in app folder successfully.
Btw when I read videos from app folder with Cursor, it doesn't refresh cursor. (It means when I record video with app and whenever I want to view videos via app, it shows old videos. even when I close app and re-open app it shows old videos. )

Here's source code.

```
public static List<MyVideo> getAppVideos(Context context) {
    final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};
    final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " = ?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = { APP_VIDEO_BUCKET_ID };
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null);
    ArrayList<MyVideo> result = new ArrayList<MyVideo>(cursor.getCount());
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        final int dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
        final int durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
        do {
            final String data = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
            final String createdDate = cursor.getString(dateColumn);
            final String durationTime = cursor.getString(durationColumn);
            result.add(new MyVideo(data, DateUtils.convertToSeconds(durationTime), "^ " +  DateUtils.getDateFromMilliSeconds(Long.parseLong(createdDate), "MMM dd, yyyy")));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;


}
```

Could anyone please suggest solution?

Comment: put all your code

Comment: you used your List<MyVideo> in private class or in your Main activity..?

Comment: Here's a link to my full source code. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ce3b1987041cf8531a5184ca33e629a

Comment: @SagarAghara Did you check?

Answer (score 1):

If CursorDemo extends CursorAdapter, then you have to use `adapter.swapCursor(cursor_update);`

That should swap the old cursor out for the new one and reload the data. With **swapCursor**,since the old cursor is not closed.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand correctly, what is cursordemo and what is cursor_update?

Comment: CursorDemo is your Class, i asked you to extend CursorAdapter. cursor_update is the Cursor which will rerun the list with new list data..